# Deploy office (web) add-in with an installer

Tags: ms-office, outlook-web-addins, word-web-addins

I started recently to build a office add-in (the web-based ones, not VSTO) and I would like in addition to have it in the office store ([the preferred method of distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish)) to also distribute the manifest through a setup file. Is this possible?

I searched around the web but the only things that come up are for VSTO add ons.

Comment: Could you clarify what you scenario you want to target with the setup file?  You can distribute the manifest and asking users or admins to install the manifest.  The installation can be a PowerShell command (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/new-app?view=exchange-ps)

Comment: I just want to distribute a installer that deploys the manifest in your system as this is still the most typical way to distribute software in Windows... Guess I could create one that runs the PowerShell command and call it a day.

Answer (score 2):

Web add-ins are not designed for distributing via standalone installers like MSI. You/administrator can sideload them for the organization unit (OU) or just install them from the store. See [Centralized Deployment via the Office 365 admin center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish#centralized-deployment-via-the-office-365-admin-center) for more information.

Comment: That seems to lack a lot of useful flexibility for larger organizations where sub-companies may have their own development / add-ins but do not control SharePoint nor want an add-in deployed across the entire organization.